# Browsers shrinking web page (except safari)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been working on a web page to handle orders and deliveries and I've run into an issue I'm not sure how to resolve. The page currently uses jQuery collapsible lists & flex box display which were presented well in Safari, but not in any other browser. The body shrinks down to what seems to be mobile view and regardless of what changes are made to margins or dimensions, it stays mobile sized.

I'm currently using jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js to structure the lists and I've already had to make a few changes to its CSS to appeal to the page's layout but I can't find anything that would be affecting the page's sizing. My question is what could be causing this? Is it on jQuery's side, or would it be a CSS issue?

Here is the template I've been using to structure everything

HTML

```
<ul id="content-list">
          <form name="form1" form method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/formmail">
            <ul style="margin:auto;">
              <ul class="background">
                <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h4>Items</h4>
                <ul class="flex-container">
                    <li class="flex-item">product name</li>
                    <li class="flex-item">producer name</li>
                    <li class="flex-item">price</li>
                    <li class="flex-item"><input type="text" placeholder="amt. here" maxlength="15"></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h4>More Items</h4>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h4>Even more items</h4>
                <ul class="flex-container2">
                    <li class="flex-item2">longer product name</li>
                    <li class="flex-item2">longer producer name</li>
                    <li class="flex-item2">price<br>price<br>price</li>
                    <li class="flex-item2">
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="amt. here" maxlength="15">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="amt. here" maxlength="15">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="amt. here"maxlength="15">
                    </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
@mixin flexbox() {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

@mixin flex($values) {
  -webkit-box-flex: $values;
  -moz-box-flex:  $values;
  -webkit-flex:  $values;
  -ms-flex:  $values;
  flex:  $values;
}

@mixin order($val) {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: $val;  
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: $val;     
  -ms-flex-order: $val;     
  -webkit-order: $val;  
  order: $val;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2% 0 4% 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
ul {
    display: flex;
}
ul:after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.flex-item {
  background: white;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
.input{
    width: 75px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.background{
    border: none; 
    margin: auto;
    width:80%;
    min-width: 80%;
    padding-right: 1cm;
    background-color:#009966;
}
#content-list {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 2cm;
}


.flex-container2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2% 0 4% 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-item2 {
  background: white;
  padding: 0;
  width: 130px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

In addition, here is the template w/ the resources I'm using:
http://jsfiddle.net/TLittler/9ndzm3cc/

Comment: Show us code, examples or anything that helps identifying the problem. Now you're just vaguely asking if anyone knows something about that horse over there, hidden behind the curtain.

Comment: Yea sorry about that. The code has been added.

Comment: One piece of advice, use chrome to develop, over 60% of the internet uses chrome, only about 4% uses safari, 8% uses IE and 22% uses firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want Safari to behave like other browsers, or the other way round, but here's what's causing the difference (at least for Safari < 9):

```
#content-list {
    display: flex;
```

If you want other browsers to behave like Safari, just set it to `block`. ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqpxu1ug/))

If you want Safari to behave like other browsers, you need to add the prefixed versions, like everywhere else: ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnsrxuco/))

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
```

Comment: I needed the other browsers to display the web page as safari did. My apologies for not making that clarification. I set the `#content-list` to block as well as the `ul` and it displays everything perfectly. Thank you.